# Leaflet Color appearing as dark blue in Choropleth

Tags: javascript, css, leaflet, mapbox

I made a choropleth using leaflet, based on population.

**Is there a property in Leaflet that suppose 5 places have population exactly 10 then do not color them at all? Something like no fill?**

I am also unable to understand why is there a dark blue color when I have set to be cream.

This is my style function . -999 just denotes the metric was not there and thats why I want to be no fill here.

```
function style(feature)
{
    return {
        fill: feature.properties.metric == -999 ? false :true,
        fillColor: getColor(feature.properties.metric),
        weight: 4,
        opacity: 1,
        color: feature.properties.metric == -999 ? '#e4e3db' :getColor(feature.properties.metric),
        dashArray: feature.properties.metric == -999 ? '' : '3',
        fillOpacity: feature.properties.metric == -999 ? 0 : 0.5
    };
}
```

[image]

Comment: I'm not an expert on leaflet, but I think this is a syntax error: `fillColor: getColor(feature.properties.)` Notice the extra period after `properties`

Comment: sorry that is only a typo here. It is not in the actual code. My other tiles have colors in them.  however only this one has a bluish color even when #e4e3db is a cream color just like background,  which is driving me crazy.

Comment: Again, not sure if it matters, but JSON requires you to put property names in quotes, like `"weight":4,"opacity":1`. I see them doing this in the leaflet tutorials on their website as well.

Comment: If that doesn't work, are you sure that `getColor(feature.properties)` returns `#e4e3db`?

Comment: Tutorial here does not require it to be in quotes. http://leafletjs.com/examples/choropleth.html   also it is very difficult to check if is actually returning that color since I have US map and it does not send this function again and again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can disable filling of polygons by using the `fill: false` option.

Reference: http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#path-options

Here's a working example on Plunker so you can verify that `fill: false` works, just comments out the `fill` property line and you'll see: Example: http://plnkr.co/edit/5Kn94H?p=preview

That blue color that shows up is Leafet's default color for polygons. So where you see blue, it must mean that there is something wrong with your statement, featuredata or getColor method. But it's hard to say since you've left out a sample of your data, the getColor method and didn't supply a testcase on Fiddle/Plunker or somewhere else.

Comment: Am I not doing that in the first line? fill: feature.properties.metric == -999 ? false :true,   
I am pretty sure that features.properties.metric is returning -999 here as otherwise the boundaries color using   color: feature.properties.metric == -999 ? '#e4e3db' :getColor(feature.properties.metric)     wont be cream.

Comment: Gave you that example so you can see and test for yourself that it works like it's supposed to. There must be something wrong with your statements or the getColor method but we're just guessing over here because you left out a sample of your data, the getColor method. Things like this can be avoided by supplying all the details and a proper testcase so we can reproduce your problem. I;ve edited my answer a little to clarify.

Comment: Edit: FIXED myself. Thanks for the option of fill:false